# Переместить изображение по нажатию

Tags: javascript, css

Хотел сделать перемещение изображения по нажатию, написал код, он не работает:

```js
knopka.onclick = function() {
  var leftImage = 100;

  document.getElementByld("imgid").style.left = leftImage + 100 + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <img id="imgid" style="position: absolute; left: 10px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
</div>
<a href="#" id="knopka">Переместить изображение</a>
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Должно быть `document.getElementById`, а не `document.getElementByld`

Comment: Благодарю! Моя невнимательность)

Comment: Рекомендую использовать разлиные IDE или текстовый редакторы с подсветкой синтаксиса, что бы таких  ошибок избежать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо:)